# Type Constraints with 2 Parameters

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object K extends Parent
defined object K

scala> case object J extends Parent
defined object J

scala> sealed trait Result 
defined trait Result

scala> case object KResult extends Result
defined object KResult

scala> case object JResult extends Result
defined object JResult
```

How can I implement the following `F`?

```
scala> def f[A <: Parent, B <: Result](x: A): B = ???
f: [A <: Parent, B <: Result](x: A)B
```

Let's say that a `K` must have a `KResult`, and `J` has a `JResult`.

But, my concern is that there's no enforced constraint on passing `f[K, JResult]` at compile-time.

Or, perhaps I could simply resort to:

```
def f(x: Parent): Result = x match {
  case K => KResult
  case J => JResult
```

But, the weakness of this approach is that I could make a mistake:

```
def badF(x: Parent): Result = x match {
  case K => JResult
  case J => KResult
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to link `KResult` with `K` in the type system. You can achieve that by adding a type parameter `A` to `Result` (optionally, it can have an upper-bound of `Parent`, but that may not be necessary).

```
sealed trait Parent

case object K extends Parent

case object J extends Parent

sealed trait Result[A]

case object KResult extends Result[K.type]

case object JResult extends Result[J.type]
```

Then, `B` can be bounded by `Result[A]`, which will enforce the fact that if `A = K`, then `B <: Result[K]`.

```
def f[A <: Parent, B <: Result[A]](x: A): B = ???

scala> f[K.type, Result[J.type]](K)
<console>:16: error: type arguments [K.type,Result[J.type]] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: Parent,B <: Result[A]]
       f[K.type, Result[J.type]](K)
        ^
```

Such a method doesn't really make a lot of sense though, because there is no way to infer the result type, it must be manually supplied. Still, that is how you would enforce those constraints.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to write `def f[A <: Parent](x: A): Result[A] = ???`